# Get firebase id

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I use firebase authentication. I need to get the firebase id when using the signInWithEmailAndPassword function. I try to get firebase id using result. But I coudn't.

**firebase Authentication function**

```
const signInresponse = await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((res)=>{
    console.log(res);
  })
  history.push('/User/Directory');
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

Comment: do you need the userId after a successful login ?

Answer (score 1):

The user id is inside the user object of the result.

```
const signInresponse = await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((res)=>{
  console.log(res.user.uid);
})
  history.push('/User/Directory');
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```